# Program that receives size of string and lets you create it letter by letter in C

Tags: c, string, input

Ive got this program which im stuck with  in which I am trying to receive the size of a string and following it, telling the user to input the letter by letter. Here is my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int size;
    int i;
    char letter;
    printf("Your string's size is...?: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    char mystring[size] ;
    for (i=0; i<size; i++){
        printf("Write a letter: \n");
        scanf("%c", &letter);
        mystring[i] = letter;

    }
    printf("%s",mystring);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

First, you need to terminate the string with a `\0`-character. Otherwise, printf will result in undefined behaviour.

Second, note that `scanf("%c",..)` will probably consume a new line left in the buffer when a user presses "enter" after having entered a number (i.e. the size).

Write:

```
char mystring[size+1] ;
for (i=0; i<size; i++){
    printf("Write a letter: \n");
    scanf("%c", &letter);
    if (i==0 && letter == '\n') {
       i--;
       continue;
    }
    mystring[i] = letter;
}
mystring[size] = '\0';

printf("%s",mystring);
```

Answer (score 4):

Two problems here.

First, the `%c` format specifier to `scanf` will read **any** character, including a newline.  You need to put a space before it to absorb any newlines in the input buffer:

```
scanf(" %c", &letter);
```

Second, you don't null-terminate the string, nor do you leave enough space in the array to store the null terminator.  Make the array one element larger, and add the null byte at the end:

```
char mystring[size+1];
for (i=0; i<size; i++){
    ...
}
mystring[size] = 0;
```

Comment: `" %c"` will consume any white space, such that any blank will be ignored then, even if it separates two words, will it? I'd suggest to ignore white spaces only at the beginning, i.e. an `ltrim`.

Comment: @StephanLechner That is correct.  OP implied that he didn't want to read spaces, but if so then the above would need to change.